# Value of $\cos (z) $ given the value of $z $

Tags: complex-numbers

What is $\cos (z) $ given $z=i\ln (2-\sqrt {3}) $ . Now I raised both sides to $e^i $ to get $e^{iz}=\cos (z)+i\sin (z)=2+\sqrt{3} $ . But that yields cos is $2+\sqrt {3}$ which isnt possible . I think that the reason this happens is that for complex numbers $(a^b)^c\neq a^{bc} $ . Thus I dont know how to solve it. Also note that answer is an integer ranging from $0-9$ . Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Defenition : $\cos(z)= \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$

Evaluating:

$$\cos(i\ln(2-\sqrt{3}))=\frac{e^{-\ln(2-\sqrt{3})} + e^{\ln(2-\sqrt{3})}}{2} = \frac{1}{4-2\sqrt{3}} + 1 -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = 2$$

> Answer: 2.
>
> Note: $\cos{z}$ (and $\sin{z}$ also) are not bounded on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: But that yields $2$ which isnt possible

Comment: Okay thanks makes sense.